# Page Flip on my website with HTML pages, not using converted PDFs

Tags: html, modx

Ok, here is my dilemma. I have a client that wants to create electronic proposals for clients. He wants to be able to create them in the MODX revo that I have built his site in.

The issue is that he wants to be able to send these proposals out to clients like a catalog, with a page flip effect. Now I have done this before using 3D issue and converting pdfs to flip books with no problem. However, he wants to basically be able to start and finish the whole thing from the cms. Creating all the web pages himself, adding in the content, images etc. then basically hitting publish and have a working flip book. I have looked into things like turn.js and pageflip but they don't offer andy trial versions and I don't want to go dropping a few hundred on software when I already have 3D issue.

Is there any way to create a flip book from straight html pages? Is Turn.js basically what I am looking for? I hate to come on here and ask such a general question but I have been looking for a solution and can't seem to come up with anything I know will work, and like I said I'm not trying to buy programs that I'm not 100% sure will do what I need them to do. I really appreciate any help/advice anyone can give me here. Thanks.

Comment: Turn.js looks like it would be the right way forward. You're going to have to take a lot of care ensuring your templates break nicely across pages, otherwise your client is going to come running back to you when he's broken things. Also, before rushing into it I would explore other more practical options rather than just going with your client's gimmicky idea. Personally, I can't stand flip brochures; they are fiddly, difficult to browse and reek of Flash. I don't even bother. Also, I imagine most people receiving a proposal would want to print it. What's wrong with an html / PDF doc instead?

Comment: I agree with you 100% okyanet, but you know how clients are sometimes, they see something they think is cool and have to have it lol. I am proposing the idea of just what you said though, html/printable pdf. I am just trying to see how long it is going to take me to go the other route if it is shot down, which I think it will be. Thanks.

Comment: Letting them know how much more it's going to cost usually does the trick ;)